# Ошибка соединения с MSSQL используя FireDAC

Tags: delphi, sql-server, firedac

В datamodule присутствуют компоненты:

```
FDManager1;
FDConnection1; 
FDQuery1;
FDGUIxWaitCursor1;
FDPhysMSSQLDriverLink1;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На моей машине, соединение проходит отлично, без каких либо ошибок или еще чего.
Но когда пытаюсь соединиться с бд у пользователя, получаю сообщения:

> SQL state: 08001. Native error: 21. Error message:  [Microsoft][SQL
> Server Native Client 11.0]Клиент не поддерживает шифрование.
>
> SQL state: 08001. Native error: -2146893051. Error message:
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]При установлении соединения
> с сервером SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с
> определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь,
> что имя экземпляра указано правильно и на сервере SQL Server разрешены
> удаленные соединения. Дополнительные сведения см. в электронной
> документации по SQL Server.

До FireDAC использовался (продолжает использоваться) ADO, работает на ура (у всех пользователей поголовно).
Никак не могу понять как исправить данную проблему.

Comment: SQL Server Native Client установлен? какая версия?

Comment: да, 11.3.6518.0